# Google+ event guest invite history

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-events

On Google Plus you can create a private event and share it with several people in your circles. You also have the option to allow guests to invite other people to the event. Is it possible to look at a history of which guests invited which people to the event?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, Google+ doesn't provide the option to view invite history, so you can't see who invited whom